# InnoDB & Isolation Levels - Aren't repeatable reads a bad thing?

Tags: mysql, innodb, isolation-level, transaction-isolation, table-locking

I was reading about `InnoDB's` [isolation levels](https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/12/20/innodb-isolation-levels/) and it makes sense for the most part, but what I don't get is why are `unrepeatable reads` a bad thing? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

For examples:

So say we had a stock column for selling products and each time someone bought an item we would take 1 item from the column, with `Repeatable read` or `serializable` isolation levels wouldn't this corrupt the data integrity?

For example:

```
TX A: start transaction;
TX B: set session transaction isolation level repeatable read;
TX B: start transaction;
TX A: select stock from products;               -- val = 8
TX B: select stock from products;               -- val = 8
TX A: update products set stock = stock - 1;    -- val = 7
TX B: select stock from products;               -- val = 8
TX A: commit
TX B: select stock from products;               -- val = 8, incorrect!
TX B: commit;
TX B: select stock from products;               -- val = 7
```

Unless it uses the CORRECT value when running an update?